# How to send data generated from one http post to a second http post in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that is being used to create an invoice. The process should be as follows:

**1.** The user specifies a customer from a drop down and then a start date and end date.

**2.** They then click on a submit button, which is linked to the controller. This then builds an IList of all the jobs that meet the above criteria.

**3.** The page refreshes and displays the list of jobs.

**4.** On the same page, there is a second form which asks for an "Invoice Date" with another submit button. Clicking this should then Update an Invoice table in my DB whilst also looping through the IList of jobs and attaching invoice ID's to them (which are stored in another table in my DB).

The issue I'm having is that I've built a method which accepts the invoice data and the IList of jobs, but when I try to pass over the IList on the second submit controller method, it's null.

In the above scenario, what's the best way to get the IList built in the first post to be used in the second post?

The only way I can think of is using some sort of temporary table to store the list of jobs after the first post and then read from this in the second when updating the invoice table. Is this an acceptable method to achieve what I want? Or is there a better way that my lack of experience is missing? xD

What bugs me about that method above is that if the user leaves the page before posting the second time, the temporary table will then have a list of rogue jobs which could be called up unexpectedly the next time.

Hope I've explained this well enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary table that you can use (which is built in MVC) is the TempData dictionary. It's persisted inside the Session, and the values get deleted when you use them.

BTW, have you thought of using Ajax instead of posting and refershing? This means that you always have the data with you, as you're on the same page. You don't have to carry state around.

---

UPDATE:

Errr wait, when you say that the list is NULL are you talking about a List recieved in your Action as a parameter? If you are, [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) shows how to databind a collection.

UPDATE 2:

I have had second thoughts about using this method (getting data from the client), as it could lead to some security issues.

If you don't want to query the DB again, TempData/Session is a possible solution.

Comment: I used your Ajax suggestion and that works fine, but I'm having problems writing to the db now. xD Thanks for the help though, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list of jobs is not modified by the user on the second page, why don't you just grab it again in the controller action that handles your second submit?